# Detecting GUI used by vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to make GUI specific settings in my `.gvimrc`.

How can I detect the GUI (`gtk3`, `gnome`, `macvim`, etc.) that vim is using?

Comment: does `$DESKTOP_SESSION` system variable help you?

Comment: @Kent I don't have any `$DESKTOP_SESSION` as I don't use DE. X11 + `fvwm2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [`has()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#has()) to test if [one of the GUI](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#feature-list) exists: `if has("gui_gnome")`, `if has("gui_win32")`, etc.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/detect-os-in-vimscript is a good reference as well